# Blood circulation and blood pressure in different tissues

Tags: blood-circulation, blood-pressure, tissue

The volume of blood coursing the blood circulation is approximately five litres. A typical vein will stretch about eight times as much as corresponding artery. Because veins have high capacitance, large changes in blood volume have little effect on arterial blood pressure.
If the volume rise or falls, the elastic walls stretch or recoil, changing the volume of blood thus blood pressure in the nervous system.

**What else tissues can we consider?**
I am interested in blood circulation and blood pressures in different tissues.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question very well-maybe try and rephrase it? As another example, low blood pressure in the kidneys is sensed by the juxtaglomerular apparatus which secretes renin into the circulation. Renin converts angiotensinogen (released by the liver) into angiotensin I. Angiotensin I is then converted into angiotensin II by angiotensin converting enzyme (this is the target of anti-hypertensives called ACE inhibitors) secreted by the lungs. Angiotensin II is a potent vasoconstrictor which directly increases the blood pressure (and hence glomerular filtration rate).  Angiotensin II also causes the release of aldosterone which acts on the kidneys to re-absorb salt and water again all facilitating an increase in blood pressure. I hope I've answered your question, if not please edit the question so it very clear.

Comment: I think you are correct. I got the exercise as is in the title. I discussed in the exam about Centers in Brain and Receptors. Basoreceptors and vasomotor center, for instance. Should I include neural regulation of blood circulation to the exercise in the title? I think now no.

Answer (score 0):

The diameter of the blood vessel affects the speed of the flow of blood. Blood flow slows down as it moves from arteries to arterioles and subsequently to the capillaries because the cross-sectional area in the capillary beds is much bigger than the arteries or any part of the circulatory system. Use this [drug awareness](http://forum.internationaldrugmart.com/) forum to know more about this.

Comment: Although the question isn't very clear, I'm not sure that this answers it and does rather read like an advert.